# Passwordless ssh into the same machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

OK, I know the basics of how to set up passwordless ssh: create a keypair using ssh-keygen then add the public key from id_dsa.pub into the host's .ssh/authorized_keys.  So for two different machines client and host, I can ssh from client into host without entering a password.  Good so far.

But I have some software which requires that client be able to ssh into *itself* without a password.  Naively I do the same thing: simply copy .ssh/id_dsa.pub into .ssh/authorized_keys, same directory.  But it doesn't work.  If I type

> user@client:~$ ssh client

then it still asks for my password, even though the public key of client is in its own authorized_keys file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Works for me.  What does "ssh -v -v -v client" tell you?

Comment: First check that your home directory, the `.ssh` directory and the `authorized_keys` file are only writable by the user, not by the group.  If it still doesn't work, post the output of `ssh -vvv client`. Also look at the server logs (e.g., `/var/log/auth.log`) if you have access to them.

Comment: Check that 1) your permissions are right and 2) you're using the correct user. There is no reason this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ssh-copy-id user@client` and it will copy the correct data to the correct place. If it's the same user as you, though, it can be problematic since it may overwrite something important. Make a copy of your `.ssh` directory before trying.

*EDIT*: Strangely enough, I tried to add my `id_rsa.pub` to my `.ssh/authorized_keys` and it worked. Are you sure that your local `sshd` is configured to accept shared key authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the default options (and default locations of the private keys) are governed by the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

However, an ssh command option allows you to specify the location of the private key to be used as well.

Answer (score -1):

Another problem that will have a similar symptom is a failure to add localhost to /etc/hosts.allow, the control file for TCP wrappers.  You can temporarily rename /etc/hosts.deny to determine if this is the source of your problem.

Comment: IF sshd were set to use tcpwrappers, and localhost was not in the hosts.allowed file, then the entire connection would be disallowed. That is an entirely different symptom.